# Pass an Parcelable Object from an Fragment to an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment `MyFragment`

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    //Some code here like to constructor

    //Trying to pass an object to another Activity
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    i.putExtra("test",  parcableObject);
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

And I have an activity `NextActivty`

```
public class NextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Some code here like to constructor
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.next_activity);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mBoard =  intent.getParcelableExtra("test");
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + mBoard);
}
```

Here is my `Board` class

```
public class Board implements Parcelable {
    //Implements all the Parcelable methods.
    protected Board(Parcel in) { 
        //Auto-generated code here
    }
    public static final Creator<Board> CREATOR = new Creator<Board>() {
        //Auto-generated code here
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        //Auto-generated code here
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        //Auto-generated code here
    }
}
```

My mBoard is always `null`.

Is there something I am not doing right here ?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. We can't see your Parcelable class nor where you initialized `parcableObject` to anything but null.

Comment: How to switch two lines in `MyFragment` as this;  `i.putExtra("test",  parcableObject); startActivity(i);`
    `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put your extra in wrong order. Put it before you start your activity.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    //Some code here like to constructor

    //Trying to pass an object to another Activity
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("test",  parcableObject);
    startActivity(i);
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

Comment: Great catch :) Thank you so much.